# Jenkins Job Migration to Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, devops, jenkins-groovy

I am searching for a way to convert existing jenkins pipeline jobs with parameters to Jenkinsfile that include the parameter within it.

Maybe xml to Jenkinsfile or something but I am yet to discover a way (found job to DSL or something like that)

I am looking to get job to scripted groovy parameter

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. please take a moment and read this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask about how to asking questions also read this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example about how to ask a good question with minimum requirement.

Comment: please share with us your workout, code snippets, error logs, or any useful information to help answer your question.